# Tent repair on Antarctic expedition

Tags: tents, repairs

I am currently endeavoring on an Antarctic expedition and wanted to know more about different repair options for our tents in down to -80 temperatures and in extreme high winds.

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you want to know about, you need to give more information to get a useful answer. Is it about what has to be done differently in low temp/high wind conditions when repairing a tent in comparison to "normal" conditions?

Comment: If you are going to be using a tent in such extreme conditions, I would strongly suggest that you should be working with a specialist manufacturer with extensive experience of the antartic and talking with their technical people, not asking on a public forum.

Comment: I would suggest you go with someone who knows those things first hand, rather than relying on theoretical knowledge anyway.

Comment: It's true that you shouldn't rely *solely* on public forums in safety relevant topics. But still, it's not a bad idea to ask those kind of questions here. You can still ask experts but maybe you get good ideas here and others can benefit from that too. Regardless this specific question is too board, I am voting to close too.

Comment: Have you selected tents already, or are you not yet at that stage?  My first thought would be to ask the people at [Hilleberg](http://us.hilleberg.com/EN/) for their advice, as this is the sort of environment they build tents for.  The forums on summitpost.org may have more people with experience in that area; this forum is a bit too general.

Comment: If weight is an issue, Hilleberg should certainly be on your shortlist. If it's more of a basecamp tent you need for scientific work etc, you could look at Snowsled: http://www.snowsled.com/scott-pyramid-tents/

Comment: @Tullochgorum What makes you think that here aren't any "specialist manufacturer['s employees etc.] with extensive experience of the Antarctic"?

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is to consult with the manufacturer, expedition grade tents are usually bomber proof but I respect that you always want to be prepared for the worst.  My strategy:

1. **Small punctures and tears:** use a cold weather tape such as [Echo All Weather Repair tape](http://shop.echotape.com/shop-all/bu-r8510-all-weather-repair-tape-50mm-x-12m-2-in-x-40-ft/) which can still form an adhesive bond in -30°C.  Apply it to both sides of the tear.  Don't bring the whole role, instead bring several metres rolled onto itself or wrapped around something that can easily placed within your coat to warm up if necessary.
2. **Larger tears:** Either bring a metre square piece of material set aside for repairs, probably the same material as the fly, or if weight is your primary concern have a strategy where you can repurpose something you've already got on hand such as the top portion of your bivvy sac, the cover of your sled, or a goretex shell.  Cold weather tape could again be used to seal the edges and the rip, but you'll want a more permanent bonding agent that adheres in cold temperatures and remains flexible.  Look for silicone glues which are rated to -30°C or lower.

Final thought: don't wait until a rip happens to discover whether your technique is viable, set aside some time at your staging camp to test out which techniques work best.

Comment: PS Best of luck Sergeant!  Perhaps while you are in Norway you can field test your repair kit options, document and share your results.